# Can ISPs see which website we visit when we use desktop VPN client and browser VPN extension?

Tags: vpn

If we user both: desktop VPN client + chrome VPN extension
or
if we use just browser's vpn extension,

does ISP see which website/link we visit?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on where your DNS requests are being sent. However, if all your network traffic is going via an encrypted VPN then no, the ISP will not see - the VPN's ISP will of course.